# vscode building and running from source hangs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm building vscode using the instructions here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source. When I get to the `yarn run watch` command, it hangs at `Finished compilation with 0 errors after 54926 ms`. What's going on?

nodejs: 8.9.4

yarn 1.3.2

npm 5.6.0

Comment: `with 0 errors` - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: In my mind, when software hangs, it has a problem. Either that, or I've done something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was running `yarn run watch` and encountered this problem.  I checked with `du -s` in the repo's folder a few times: no change, so I killed the command.

After killing `yarn run watch` I then ran `yarn watch` and once again it hung with the same error. I checked with `du` again. No change. I killed that command too.

I then ran

```
./scripts/code.sh
```

And VS Code started fine. So in my experience, **it is fine to kill the yarn command**.